How Matrix Elements are getting changed?

My Question is when I am initializing matrix2 with case1 approach I am getting the right answer, but when I am initialising matrix 2 with case2 approach I am getting wrong ans.
The if condition is executing on matrix[1][2], I am not able to understand where I am making a mistake
int matrix[][] = {{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1}};
    CASE 1 - int matrix2[][]= {{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1}};

    CASE 2 - int matrix2[][]=matrix;

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix2));
     for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++){
            if(matrix[i][j]==0){

                // making col= 0
                for(int k=0;k<matrix2.length;k++){
                    matrix2[k][j]=0;
                }

                // making row = 0
                for(int k=0;k<matrix2.length;k++){
                    matrix2[i][k]=0;
                }
                
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix2));

I am initialising it with case2 as in LEETCODE matrix will be different each time

What do you think matrix2[][]=matrix does?  And what do you see if you print matrix[k][j] before and after you do matrix2[k][j]=0;?

BTW it is recommended to write int[][] array instead of int array[][]

@ScottHunter matrix2 [ ][ ] = matrix is initializing matrix2 = matrix1. I printed it to be sure.
But I am not making any change in matrix how its elements are changing? please explain
I have debugged several times. not sure what I am missing

(matrix2 = matrix; does not copy values or so - both variables are (pointing to) the same instance - changing one will also change the other - from first comment, if you do matrix2[k][j] = 0, matrix[k][j], the same element, will also be 0)

@user85421 really thanks buddy, I really missed the memory management concepts on the code.

Case 2 is not copying the values into matrix2. Instead both matrix and matrix2 variables are pointing to same memory. So any change in matrix2 or matrix will look like changing in both. Even though array holds Primitive types, internally it allocates memory just like any other Java Objects.
int matrix[][] = {{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1}};
int matrix2[][]=matrix;

Solution:
Do a deep copy / clone the array. Creates a independent copy in memory, so any change in matrix2 or matrix will not affect each other.
int matrix[][] = {{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1}};
int matrix2[][] = Arrays.stream(matrix) .map(int[]::clone) .toArray(int[][]::new);


Hey, Really thanks for this amazing explanation. I haven't thought about the reference variables. Thanks again for the help

I really appreciate you have taken the time to explain so in depth.
